# no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-12-14')

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-rest, localdate

This question is almost same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110371/no-string-argument-constructor-factory-method-to-deserialize-from-string-value) one, but it differs in that I am trying to get String to LocalDate. Here is error from STS:

> 2018-12-14 00:47:04.507  WARN 6216 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDate:
>   no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from
>   String value ('2018-12-14'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of java.time.LocalDate: no String-argument
>   constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
>   ('2018-12-14')  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@73ff9989;
>   line: 3, column: 16] (through reference chain:
>   com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.model.request.ReservationRequest["checkin"])]

and here is from Postman:

> {
>       "timestamp": 1544744824516,
>       "status": 400,
>       "error": "Bad Request",
>       "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
>       "message": "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDate: no String-argument constructor/factory method to
>   deserialize from String value ('2018-12-14'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of java.time.LocalDate: no String-argument
>   constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
>   ('2018-12-14')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@73ff9989;
>   line: 3, column: 16] (through reference chain:
>   com.xxxxx.xxxxx.model.request.ReservationRequest[\"checkin\"])",
>       "path": "/room/reservation/v1" }

And POST request was:

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "checkin": "2018-12-14",
    "checkout": "2018-12-17"
}
```

Where relevant classes are:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

@Configuration
public class ApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectWriter objectWriter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

public class ReservationRequest {

    private Long id;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate checkin;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate checkout;

    public ReservationRequest() {
        super();
    }

    public ReservationRequest(Long id, LocalDate checkin, LocalDate checkout) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.checkin = checkin;
        this.checkout = checkout;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDate getCheckin() {
        return checkin;
    }

    public void setCheckin(LocalDate checkin) {
        this.checkin = checkin;
    }

    public LocalDate getCheckout() {
        return checkout;
    }

    public void setCheckout(LocalDate checkout) {
        this.checkout = checkout;
    }
}
```

and

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.model.request.ReservationRequest;
import com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.model.response.ReservationResponse;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(ResourceConstants.ROOM_RESERVATION_V1)
public class ReservationResource {

    @RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> getAvaiableRooms(
            @RequestParam(value = "checkin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkin,
            @RequestParam(value = "checkout") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkout) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> createReservation(@RequestBody ReservationRequest reservationRequest) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponse> updateReservation(@RequestBody ReservationRequest reservationRequest) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ReservationResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{reservationId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteReservation(@PathVariable long reservationId) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

I've included imports just in case.

Anyway, if I change ReservationRequest to have fields with Strings instead of LocalDate like this then it doesn't produce error

```
public class ReservationRequest {

    private Long id;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private String checkin;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private String checkout;

    public ReservationRequest() {
        super();
    }

    public ReservationRequest(Long id, String checkin, String checkout) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.checkin = checkin;
        this.checkout = checkout;
    }

(getters and setters updated as well)
```

JDK 1.8; springBootVersion = '1.5.17.RELEASE'; name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.7'

Question is why it doesn't work as intended with **LocalDate**?

UPDATE: tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format) solutions, and added @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize, as neither `objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);`
        or `objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);`

worked so now it looks like:

```
public class ReservationRequest {

    private Long id;
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    //@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate checkin;
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    //@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate checkout;

    public ReservationRequest() {
        super();
    }
```

So, now it looks like it works but I don't know if it is good solution?

Comment: [FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8: Set of support modules for Java 8 datatypes (Optionals, date/time) and features (parameter names)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)

Comment: Tried it - didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is here

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

You must return configured `objectMapper` instead of new instance:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()
            .addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy")))
            .addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy"))))
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue recently and reason for the error was there are double quotes around my json string which when I removed it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score -2):

I think its too late for me to reply on the post I have faced the same issue the below annotation was helpful.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
```

:)